# Is it possible to rotate annotation labels in Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Is it possible to rotate a labels (not feature labels but manual annotations) in Print Composer in QGIS 1.8?

Comment: What type of label? feature label or manual annotation?

Comment: @user20828 Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Could you please explain your question in detail?

Comment: manual annotations

Answer (score 1):

Labels that you add manually when in the Print Composer (as opposed to labels applied to a layer) can be rotated in QGIS 1.9 (after a fashion) on but not in QGIS 1.8.

In the latest release of QGIS 1.9, go to the print composer and add a label.  Then in the item properties expand the 'Display' section and add a value for rotate.  The background is expanded to accommodate the rotated label (hence my comment 'after a fashion' above!), so I think it looks best to turn the background off.

If you want to rotate labels on a layer then use the advanced (data driven) labeling capability.